# How to report result to the nearest 0.01 mg/L?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

what is meant by reporting result to the nearest 0.01 mg/L?
The test result in certificate show 7 mg/L showing no decimal point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reporting to the nearest quantity means that you report as many decimal places of the quantity as suggested. This is a common analytical chemistry expression given in procedures or analytical protocols. For example, if we say weigh  $\pu{5 g} \; \ce{KOH}$ to the nearest $\pu{0.1 g}$, one would record the weight to one decimal place, *e.g.*, $\pu{5.1 g}$ or $\pu{5.3 g}$, to one decimal place but you will not report $\pu{5.1176 g} \; \ce{KOH}$ even if your balance is capable of doing so.

Your test report should include at least two decimal places, the report should appear as $\pu{7.24 mg/L}$ or something like that number.

Answer (score 1):

If the quoted value is 7 mg/l and there is no other information given, this means that we must assume that the value has been rounded and is thus between 6.5 and 7.5 mg/l, i.e. $7\pm 0.5$ mg/l.

If a result $X$ is given to nearest 0.01 mg/l or 1% this means that we must assume that the value was rounded up from $X\pm 0.005$  mg/l.